# How to transfer Ether between accounts in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, transactions, accounts, addresses, balances

I'd like get ether balance of account in solidity. I tried the following, but it didn't work. Could you tell me how to do it?

```
contract MultiplyContract{
    address public buyer;
    address public seller;
    uint public price;
    function MultiplyContract(
      address _buyer,
      address _seller,
      uint _price,
      ){
      buyer = _buyer;
      seller = _seller;
      price = _price;
    }
    function Execution (address _buyer, address _seller) {
    eth.getBalance(_buyer) -=  price; 
    eth.getBalance(_seller) += price;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A contract can read any balance using address.balance like: `_buyer.balance`

A contract can send **its** Ether in units of wei using address.send like: `seller.send(price)`

A contract cannot subtract from an arbitrary address.

Using `send` subtracts from the balance of the contract, so if the contract has a balance, it could do:

```
function Execution (address _seller) {
    seller.send(price);
}
```

Comment: You should use `transfer` instead.

Comment: `transfer` was added later on, and yes it is safer in most cases. It is also important to be aware of cases where a contract can get stuck by using `transfer`: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/74007/42

Answer (score 14):

[`address.transfer()`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related)

- throws on failure
- forwards `2,300` gas stipend, safe against reentrancy
- should be used in most cases as it's the safest way to send ether

[`address.send()`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related)

- returns `false` on failure
- forwards `2,300` gas stipend, safe against reentrancy
- should be used in rare cases when you want to handle failure in the contract

[`address.call.value().gas()()`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related)

- returns `false` on failure
- forwards all available gas, allows specifying how much gas to forward
- should be used when you need to control how much gas to forward when sending ether or to call a function of another contract

More details here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/38642/18932

Answer (score 8):

Please refer to [address methods documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#address-related).

You should prefer to use `transfer` over `send`:

> There are some dangers in using `send`: The transfer fails if the call stack depth is at 1024 (this can always be forced by the caller) and it also fails if the recipient runs out of gas. So in order to make safe Ether transfers, always check the return value of send, use `transfer` or even better: Use a pattern where the recipient withdraws the money.

Answer (score 0):

//for transferring ether to another address at first you need to make your owner account payable, means you can add value to that when deploy the program in remix.
//with below program you can check how ether transfer between accounts in remix

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
//address  public address2=0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db; //sample reciever
contract sendether{
    address payable public owner;
    bytes public data;
    constructor()payable {
     owner=payable(msg.sender);   
    }
   
    uint public contractbalance;//contract value 
    uint public ownerbalance;
    uint public balanceto;
    
    function sendviacall(address payable _to,uint _value)public payable{//returns(bool sent,byte memory data) {
        (bool sent,)=_to.call{value: _value}("");
        ownerbalance=owner.balance;
        balanceto=_to.balance;
        contractbalance=address(this).balance;
        require(sent,"failed to send");
    }
}`
```