# Can I move ether of one arbitrary account to another one by a contract automatically?

Tags: solidity

I'd like to move ether from one arbitrary account to another account following a contract.  From the execution method, I'd like to send ether.  Can I do that?

```
contract MultiplyContract{
    address public sender;
    address public receiver;
    uint public price;
    function MultiplyContract(
      address _sender,
      address _receiver,
      uint _price
      ){
      sender = _sender;
      receiver = _receiver;
      price = _price;
    }
    function Execution(){
      //sender send ether to receiver//
    }
    function () {
      throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the question still needs to be clarified, maybe use "arbitrary account to another one"...  Otherwise the answer is going to be the same as http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/how-to-transfer-ether-between-accounts-in-solidity

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @NickJohnson I'd like to make swap trading account. According to the contract info, I'll want let it move ether from one account to another.

Comment: @toshikaseda The way to do that is to hold ether in the contract, and keep a map recording individual account balances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. A contract can only spend Ether from its own funds. Being able to sign a transaction for an arbitrary account would entail the contract having access to said account's private key, making it public for everyone.

Comment: Thank you Péter. Btw, I'd like to realise derivative,  that move ether of one eoa to another one according to a contract. Can I actualise it?