# send() ether transfer not happening

Tags: solidity

I am trying to send ether from one contract to another by getting the input address. Here A has a balance of 100 ether.

1) contract B is created first and I have the address
2) contract A is created next
3) invoking fundTransfer() function with B's address and 50 ether as amount.

Transfer isn't happening. what am i missing here. Sorry if it is a basic question.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract A {

    function A () payable {

    }

    event balanc(uint a);

    function fundTransfer(address b,uint amt) {
       bool ret = b.send(amt);
    }    

    function getBalance() {
        balanc(this.balance);
    }
}

contract B {

    event balanc(uint a);

    function getBalance() {
        balanc(this.balance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will work:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract A {
    function A() payable {
    }

    function fundTransfer(address b, uint256 amt) {
       bool ret = b.send(amt);
    }    

    function getBalance() constant returns (uint256 balance) {
        balance = this.balance;
    }
}

contract B {
    function getBalance() constant returns (uint256 balance) {
        balance = this.balance;
    }

    function () payable {
    }
}
```

The main difference to your original source code is that I have added the fallback `()` function marked with the `payable` modifier. Your events work, but I have just replaced your events with constant functions.

Following are the screens that show you how to deploy it using the JavaScript VM with [Browser Solidity (or Remix)](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.9+commit.364da425.js).

The first screen below shows the deployment of contract `B` to the address `0xde6a66562c299052b1cfd24abc1dc639d429e1d6`. Note that **Value** is set to 0.

[image]

In the next screen, I have set **Value** to 100 (ethers) and deployed contract `A`. Note that `A.getBalance()` returns an error - this is because a value of 100 ethers is sent when invoking `A.getBalance()` and this function is not marked with the `payable` modifier.

[image]

In the next screen, I have set **Value** to 0 and clicked on `getBalance()` and the returned result shows that contract `A` has been successfully deployed with 100 ethers.

[image]

In the next screen, I will execute `A.fundTransfer(...)` with the parameters `"0xde6a66562c299052b1cfd24abc1dc639d429e1d6","50000000000000000000"`. Note that the `"50000000000000000000"` number will need to be quoted or the number will cause an error.

[image]

And the next screen shows the successful transfer of 50 ethers from `A` to `B`. You can also check that `A.getBalance()` returns a value of 50 ethers.

[image]

If you remove the `function () payable { }` from contract `B`, the exercise above will fail.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should check [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3650/5977). It seems related.

The balance shall get deducted from the **contract**, not **A**'s account.

for deducting the amount from contract, you have to pass some ethers in **value** field, while calling the function. 
e.g.

```
myContractInstance.myMethod(arg1,arg2,...,{value:web3.fromWei((1 ether), gas: 600000 }, function(err, result){...});
```

Hope this helps.