# <address>.send vs <address>.transfer best practice usage?

Tags: solidity, security, address.transfer

I noticed that address's offer two member functions that perform the transfer of ether to the specified address. `send` returns `false` upon failure and `transfer` raises an exception. In the Solidity documentation they offer an example that utilizes both calls [Simple Open Auction](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/solidity-by-example.html#simple-open-auction).

When should I use `send` and when should I use `transfer`?

Comment: Also a nice breakdown of the differences between `send` and `transfer`: https://vomtom.at/solidity-send-vs-transfer/

Comment: Dec 2019: `call.value()()` should now be used for transferring ether.  (send and transfer should be avoided.)

See:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78124/is-transfer-still-safe-after-the-istanbul-update-2300-gas-limitation

Answer (score 61, accepted):

### EDIT May 2021: `call{value: amount}("")` should now be used for transferring ether (Do not use `send` or `transfer`.)

Here's an example:

```
(bool success, ) = recipient.call{value:amt}("");
require(success, "Transfer failed.");
```

Please see:

- [Is transfer() still safe after the Istanbul update?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78124/is-transfer-still-safe-after-the-istanbul-update-2300-gas-limitation)
- https://diligence.consensys.net/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/

TLDR; `transfer` and `send` should be avoided because they forward a fixed amount of gas and gas costs can and will change.

### Original Answer

Both `send` and `transfer` are considered to be a safe way to move funds as they have a gas stipend of 2300.

If you are curious about the reasons for adding a transfer you may follow an original [discussion](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/610) about the feature.

Comment: If `send` fails, it returns false, correct?  What does `transfer` do if it fails?  Does it return false?  Does it revert all changes?

Comment: Transfer throw an exception and all of the changes in a transaction are reverted.

Comment: Dec 2019: `call.value()()` should now be used for transferring ether.  (send and transfer should be avoided.)

See:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78124/is-transfer-still-safe-after-the-istanbul-update-2300-gas-limitation

I will clean up this comment if this answer is updated.

Comment: Well, if you're going to now advise people to not use `send` or `transfer`, something should be said about reentrancy, as that was the point of the 2300 gas stipend for the other approaches (misguided as they turned out to be).

Comment: Besides the checks-effect and guarding methods to preven reentrancy, would it also be secure to use `recipient.call{gas: 3000, value:amt}("");`?
(I just used `3000` as a gas amount here, ofc this can be adjusted accordingly)

Comment: Why in 2021 you cannot use send and transfer ? Manuals says it's safe. And the gas set to 2300

Comment: @RusAlex I've updated the answer with a TLDR; about why `transfer` and `send` should be avoided. You might also want to look at this [post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/78124/24693).

Answer (score 101):

[`address.transfer()`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related)

- throws on failure
- forwards `2,300` gas stipend (not adjustable), safe against reentrancy
- should be used in most cases as it's the safest way to send ether

[`address.send()`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related)

- returns `false` on failure
- forwards `2,300` gas stipend (not adjustable), safe against reentrancy
- should be used in rare cases when you want to handle failure in the contract

[`address.call.value().gas()()`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related)

- returns `false` on failure
- forwards all available gas (adjustable), not safe against reentrancy
- should be used when you need to control how much gas to forward when sending ether or to call a function of another contract

---

*Detailed version below:*

The relative tradeoffs between the use of `someAddress.send()`, `someAddress.transfer()`, and `someAddress.call.value()()`:

- `someAddress.send()`and `someAddress.transfer()` are considered safe against reentrancy. While these methods still trigger code execution, the called contract is only given a stipend of 2,300 gas which is currently only enough to log an event.
- `x.transfer(y)` is equivalent to `require(x.send(y))`, it will automatically revert if the send fails.
- `someAddress.call.value(y)()` will send the provided ether and trigger code execution. The executed code is given all available gas for execution making this type of value transfer unsafe against reentrancy.

Using `send()` or `transfer()` will prevent reentrancy but it does so at the cost of being incompatible with any contract whose fallback function requires more than 2,300 gas. It is also possible to use `someAddress.call.value(ethAmount).gas(gasAmount)()` to forward a custom amount of gas.

One pattern that attempts to balance this trade-off is to implement both a [push and pull](https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/recommendations/#favor-pull-over-push-for-external-calls) mechanism, using `send()` or `transfer()` for the push component and `call.value()()` for the pull component.

It is worth pointing out that exclusive use of `send()` or `transfer()` for value transfers does not itself make a contract safe against reentrancy but only makes those specific value transfers safe against reentrancy.

More details are here https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/recommendations/#be-aware-of-the-tradeoffs-between-send-transfer-and-callvalue

Reasons for adding `transfer()`: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/610

---

`call()` can also be used to issue a low-level `CALL` opcode to make a message call to another contract:

```
if (!contractAddress.call(bytes4(keccak256("someFunc(bool, uint256)")), true, 3)) {
    revert;
}
```

The forwarded `value` and `gas` can be customized:

```
contractAddress.call.gas(5000)
    .value(1000)(bytes4(keccak256("someFunc(bool, uint256)")), true, 3);
```

This is equivalent to using a function call on a contract:

```
SomeContract(contractAddress).someFunc.gas(5000)
    .value(1000)(true, 3);
```

Beware of the right padding of the input data in `call()` https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2884

---

`transfer()`, `send()` and `call()` functions are translated by the Solidity compiler into the `CALL` opcode.

As explained on the [Subtleties](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Subtleties) page in the Ethereum's wiki:

> CALL has a multi-part gas cost:
>
> - 700 base
> - 9000 additional if the value is nonzero
> - 25000 additional if the destination account does not yet exist (note: there is a difference between zero-balance and nonexistent!)
>
> The child message of a nonzero-value CALL operation (NOT the top-level message arising from a transaction!) gains an additional 2300 gas on top of the gas supplied by the calling account; this stipend can be considered to be paid out of the 9000 mandatory additional fee for nonzero-value calls. This ensures that a call recipient will always have enough gas to log that it received funds.

---

Sending and Receiving ether explained in [Solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html#sending-and-receiving-ether):

Comment: Very nice post :D Can I ask a question: so if I use transfer/send, I will **always** lost 2300 gas right ? There is no refund policy.

Comment: Thank you. You will always lose at least 9700 gas when you make a send/transfer. 2300 is the stipend that the internal transaction will be able to spend. This is how it's explained in the Subtleties page: The child message of a nonzero-value CALL operation (NOT the top-level message arising from a transaction!) gains an additional 2300 gas on top of the gas supplied by the calling account; this stipend can be considered to be paid out of the 9000 mandatory additional fee for nonzero-value calls. This ensures that a call recipient will always have enough gas to log that it received funds.

Comment: This answer should be the validated answer as it provide the most comprehensive explanation on which to use in the different scenarios. The current answer is also a very good answer as well, but it describes more the historical context of the feature.

Comment: @medvedev1088 which of those methods in your posts returns false if the contract returns null?

Comment: What value is returned by transfer on success?

Answer (score 5):

Very good answers above but please note the change in syntax in the latest version of Solidity.

From [Solidity Docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.10/types.html#address):

```
address(nameReg).call{gas: 1000000, value: 1 ether}(abi.encodeWithSignature("register(string)", "MyName"));
```

Answer (score 4):

EDIT Dec 2019: `call.value()()` should now be used for transferring ether. (Do not use send or transfer.)

See:
[Is transfer() still safe after the Istanbul update?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78124/is-transfer-still-safe-after-the-istanbul-update-2300-gas-limitation)

Comment: sender.transfer{gas:10000}(2 ether) is it also ok to set the gas limit with transfer. On one of two different sources, I read it will be possible in the future. On the other, I read it can be set like the sample I provided.

Comment: @Ferda-Ozdemir-Sonmez You should use `sender.call{value: 2 ether}("")`.  You should avoid transfer and specifying gas.  Additional info: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78124/is-transfer-still-safe-after-the-istanbul-update

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I know that. I am asking if sender.transfer{gas:10000}(2 ether)  works ?

Comment: That's not reliable. Sometimes it might work, sometimes not. And it would be permanently broken if 10,000 gas is never enough. You can't assume 10,000 gas will always be enough. The answers have explained how people assumed 2,300 gas was enough before, well it wasn't. The lesson is to not assume that 10,000 gas will also be enough.

Comment: I will not use it, I am preparing an educational material.. Don't worry..