# How send eth from a smart cotract

Tags: contract-development, mist, tokens

For example, I have 10 eth on my smart contract. How I send eth on another address?

Comment: In solidity you should use transfer or send https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19341/address-send-vs-address-transfer-best-practice-usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the following functions :

```
destination_Address.send()

destination_Address.transfer()

destination_Address.call.value()
```

however you should be **aware** of the tradeoffs between send(), transfer(), and call.value()().

> **x.transfer(y)** is equivalent to **if (!x.send(y)) throw;** Send is the low
>   level counterpart of transfer, and it's advisable to use transfer when
>   possible. **someAddress.send()** and **someAddress.transfer()** are considered
>   **safe** against reentrancy. While these methods still trigger code
>   execution, the called contract is only given a stipend of 2,300 gas
>   which is currently only enough to log an event.
>   **someAddress.call.value()()** will send the provided ether and trigger
>   code execution. The executed code is given all available gas for
>   execution making this type of value transfer unsafe against
>   reentrancy. Using send() or transfer() will prevent reentrancy but it
>   does so at the cost of being incompatible with any contract whose
>   fallback function requires more than 2,300 gas.
>
> One pattern that attempts to balance this trade-off is to implement
>   both a push and pull mechanism, using send() or transfer() for the
>   push component and call.value()() for the pull component.

It is worth pointing out that exclusive use of send() or transfer() for value transfers does not itself make a contract safe against reentrancy, but only makes those specific value transfers safe against reentrancy.

read more at : https://github.com/ConsenSys/smart-contract-best-practices#integer-overflow-and-underflow