# Solidity <address>.send() doesn't create a separate transaction?

Tags: solidity, truffle, transactions, ganache

I am new to Ethereum and I deployed a contract in `Ganache` which has a function like this:

```
function withdraw(uint256 amount) public payable returns(bool) {
    require(accounts[msg.sender].balance >= amount);
    accounts[msg.sender].balance -= amount;
    bool r = msg.sender.send(amount);
    if (!r){
        accounts[msg.sender].balance += amount;
    }
    return r;   
}
```

Then, I use `Truffle console` to send transactions calling function `withdraw`. 
I expected there should be two transactions: one is calling function `withdraw` and another is the contract sending ether to the sender, which is a result of `msg.sender.send(amount)`.

But I only got one transaction in Ganache which about calling function `withdraw`.

Am I understanding `<address>.send()` wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is quoted from others.

> The `transfer()` or `send()` or `call()` function doesn't result in a
>   transaction. It results in a [message call](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#message-calls) inside the original
>   transaction initiated by an [external account](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#accounts). The blockchain will
>   record a single transaction no matter how many `transfer()` or
>   `call()` or `send()` invocations there are in the code.

I just put the [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/38638/51356) here for reference.