# Call address.transfer() with Gas Limit and Price from another function

Tags: solidity, gas, ico

I have a smart contract where user can transfer ETH to an ICO. Like this

```
function buyICO(paymentAddress, amount) {

// do some other important things

// transfer the amount to the payment address
paymentAddress.transfer(amount);

}
```

Because some ICOs require a specific gas price and limit, but I can't set these in the transfer function. I can set it when user call buyICO() function but I don't know how do I calculate the gas limit and price for the whole thing.

What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to adjust gas limit you should use address.call.value().gas()(). See this answer for more details [<address>.send vs <address>.transfer best practice usage?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19341/address-send-vs-address-transfer-best-practice-usage/38642#38642) You can't adjust the gas price though.

Comment: sweeet, thanks for this! exactly what I needed. however would this be a problem that I can't adjust gas price? it is often required by ICOs to set a certain price and limit when participating.

Comment: Then you will have to set the gas price when calling buyICO() in the top level transaction. The internal call .transfer() inherits this price.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped