# how to transfer a specific balance from a smart contract?

Tags: solidity

Whenever someone buys a smart-contract the amount (in Wei) get stored in SC(Smart Contract) `address(this) += msg.value`.

Now I am trying to create a function to redeem the balance of the SC

```
function redeemInvTokens(uint256 _amount) public returns(bool){
    require(_amount <= amount, "you cannot redeem the more tokens");
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _amount;
    msg.sender.call.value(address(this).balance - (address(this).balance - _amount))("Transferred ether to financier");
    return true;
}
```

but its not transferring any amount to the `msg.sender`.

How to transfer the specific amount to the `msg.sender`? so I don't have to use `address(this).balance - (address(this).balanace - _amount)`.

Comment: "so I don't have to use `address(this).balance - (address(this).balanace - _amount)`"??? This expression is equivalent to `_amount`, what brought you to the conclusion that you need to use it in order to transfer the specific amount to the sender? You can simply do `msg.sender.transfer(_amount)`.

Comment: Also, what is `amount` in `require(_amount <= amount, ...)`? You should post a working example. This symbol (`amount`) is not defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: `msg.sender.call.value(_amount)()` it is not transfering any amount to `msg.sender` so i used `msg.sender.call.value(address(this).balance)()`. but, again i want to send specific amount to `msg.sender` thats why that calculation to determine.

Comment: `x - (x - y) == y`!!!

Comment: And on top of that of that, why not simply do `msg.sender.transfer(_amount)`?

Comment: but isn't this method should be avoided after Istanbul update?

Comment: That one I'm not sure of (I mean, I've never heard of, so it would be reckless of me to rule it out). AFAIK, this is the primary (and recommended) method for transferring ether from your contract to some address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use call with gas estimation.

for example,

> `require(address(receiverAdr).call.value(_amount).gas(35000)());`

In your case:

```
uint256 transferableAmount = address(this).balance -(address(this).balance - _amount);
 require(msg.sender.call.value(transferableAmount).gas(35000)());;
```

Comment: but isn't this method should be avoided after Istanbul update https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/19343/50405

Comment: Yes. but you don't mention the exact error msg or transaction hash of transferred amount so. Don't worry I have edited the answer. pls check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample example

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
        pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
        
        /**
         * @title SimpleVault
         * @dev Store & retrieve Funds from the contract
         * @custom:dev-run-script ./scripts/deploy_with_ethers.ts
         */
        contract SimpleVault {
            address payable owner;
        
            constructor () payable {
                owner = payable(msg.sender);
            }
        
            function withdraw() public {
                   payable (msg.sender).transfer(getBalance());     // Transfer to msg.sender
       OR
                // payable (0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2).transfer(getBalance());  // Transfer to a specific address
       OR
               (bool success, ) = address(0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2).call{value:getBalance()}("");
            require(success, "Transfer failed."); 
    
    }
        
            function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
               return address(this).balance;
            }
        }
```