# How do i send the rest of the ether to a smart contract.Solidity

Tags: solidity

Hello I'm just making an easy smart contract. By reading it you should understand it.

```js
contract Idk {
    Thing[] deployedThings;

    function createSomething(address  _name) public {
        Thing newThing=new Thing(_name);
        deployedThings.push(newThing);
    }

    function seeThings() public view returns(Thing[] memory){
        return deployedThings;
    }

}

contract Thing {
    
    address name;
    constructor(address _name ) {
        name= _name;  
    }

    function sendEth() public payable {
        require(msg.value==1 ether);
        payable(name).send(0.2 ether);
    }
 }
```

So the problem is that when i send 0.2 to the address the rest of ether goes to the Thing smart contract but i would like to send the rest of the ether to the Idk contract. Is it possible to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it.

1. You'll have to bind the parent address (*IDK*) to the child contract (*Thing*), so it can send funds back to it. See `createSomething()` where we send `address(this)` when we create a new item.
2. *Thing* will save this second argument as the parent.
3. In the `sendEth()` method, we'll split 0.2 to the `name` (I suggest picking a more intuitive variable name here) and 0.8 to the `parent`. We make sure to check the transfer statuses so they don't fail.
4. We have to instruct *IDK* to receive funds, using the `receive()` fallback method.

Note: for transferring tokens, we'll use the `call` format. More on this [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19341/address-send-vs-address-transfer-best-practice-usage/38642).

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Idk {
    Thing[] deployedThings;

    function createSomething(address  _name) public returns (address) {
        Thing newThing= new Thing(_name, address(this));
        deployedThings.push(newThing);
        return address(newThing);
    }

    function seeThings() public view returns(Thing[] memory){
        return deployedThings;
    }

    // instruct the contract to accept ETH or it will revert without it

    receive() payable external {}     
 }


contract Thing {

     address public name;
     address public parent;

    constructor(address _name, address _parent) {
        name= _name;
        parent = _parent; // bind the factory/parent address
    }

    function sendEth() public payable {
        require(msg.value==1 ether, "Value has to be 1 ether");

        (bool success1, ) = name.call{value: 0.2 ether}("");
        require(success1, "First transfer failed");
        
        (bool success2, ) = parent.call{value: 0.8 ether}("");
        require(success2, "First transfer failed");
    }
}
```